# CakePHP form, printing out certain queries

Tags: cakephp, foreach

hi all just wanting to know if you were printing stuff out in a foreach loop how would you code it so that only a specific set of data pertaining to that person. For example I want it to print when active in my relationships table is =false or 0

this is the current code I have in my view.

```
            <?php foreach($Relationships as $relationship):?>


                <tr> 

                    <td align='center'><?php echo $relationship['Relationship']['partyone']; ?></td>
                    <td align='center'><?php echo $relationship['Relationship']['partytwo']; ?></td>
                    <td> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $this->Html->link('approve', array('action'=>'approve', $relationship['Relationship']['id'])); ;?>
                    <td><?php echo $this->Html->link('Decline', array('action'=>'decline', $relationship['Relationship']['id'])); ;?>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in my find condition in the controller, not the view. here is the line of code I had to write for my controller

```
$this->set('Relationships', $this->Relationship->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Relationship.partytwo' => $userid,'Relationship.active'=>false))));
```